# Entering from text file into an object array

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

My question heading might be typed out wrong.. But I'll try to explain it properly here. 
I've a class called Sales with some attributes. Here is that class:

```
protected String salesNo;
protected String customerName;
protected int day ;
protected int month;
protected int year;
protected double totalPrice;

public Sales(String salesNo, String customerName, int day, int month, int year, double totalPrice)
{
    this.salesNo = salesNo;
    this.customerName = customerName;
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice;

}
```

I need to have a list of sales with those attributes. Now in a different class I've written the following method code:

```
static Sales salesdata[] = new Sales[50]; // declared in database class OUTside any method
```

Now here is the troublesome method:

```
public static Sales readToArray(String filename)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{
            //local variables
    String salesNo = null;
    String customerName = null;
    int day = 0;
    int month = 0;
    int year = 0;
    double price = 0;

    Sales sale = new Sales(salesNo, customerName, day, month, year, price);
    String temp[] = new String[100];  //array to hold the file items as a string

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) //limited the words in file to exactly 20..
    {
        temp[i] = in.readLine();            //words entered into an array
    }
    System.out.println("First pass");
for(int i=0; i<50; i++) //limited the words in file to exactly 
    {
         System.out.println(temp[i]);

    }

    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    if(temp[i] != " ")
    {
        salesNo = temp[i];
        i++;
        customerName = temp[i]; 
        i++;
        day = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]); 
        i++;
        month = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
        i++;
        year = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
        i++;
        price = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);  
        i++;
        salesdata[count] = new Sales(salesNo, customerName, day, month, year, price);
        System.out.println(day);
        count++;

    }

    System.out.println("After passing");


    System.out.println("MAINTEST");
    System.out.println(salesdata[0].salesNo);       
System.out.println(salesdata[0].customerName);
System.out.println(salesdata[0].day);
System.out.println(salesdata[0].month);
System.out.println(salesdata[0].year);
System.out.println(salesdata[0].totalPrice);
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(salesdata[1].salesNo);       
System.out.println(salesdata[1].customerName);
System.out.println(salesdata[1].day);
System.out.println(salesdata[1].month);
System.out.println(salesdata[1].year);
System.out.println(salesdata[1].totalPrice);
    return sale;
}
```

Right now only with this code i am getting the salesdata(0) correctly.. and not the next ones.. How can i fix that?

One more thing: This is just a small method I'm having trouble with. The actual program is a GUI program.. so please excuse the variables assigned and stuff like that, I'll fix it before integrating with the GUI. Just need to make sure that this part works..  :)

Also, i understand that using  for(int i=0; **i<50**; i++) isn't very effective. But I've tried using `i<filename.length()` but that only gives the length of 9 it seems..  How can i write a inequality for the length of words in the file?

I would really glad if anyone can give some guild lines on how to fix this code.
 Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some problems. If I understand it correctly, I'd do something like:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(in);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);

int words=0;
int count=0;
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    salesdata[count++] = new Sales(scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), can.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextDouble());         
    //if ((words+=6)>=50) break;
}
```

Anf if you want limit the input to 50 words just uncomment the `if`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what else is wrong with your code but the if condition is not in a loop. It's only executed once for i = 0 and count = 0, which means this line is executed only once as well:

```
salesdata[count] = new Sales(salesNo, customerName, day, month, year, price);
```

Comment: Oh yea! I didnt realize it wasnt looped. Thanks. But that is the whole ordeal for me right now. If i loop it im getting a NumberFormatException.